# Expected an indent block

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting a warning saying

> "Expected an indent block"

on the last line but can't figure out exactly what the issue is. I just need the code to run without the issue. I can delete whatever is causing the issue or comment it out for now.

```
def Weather():
    zipcode = input('Please enter zipcode: ')
    wcpage = requests.get('https://weather.com/weather/today/l/' + zipcode,verify=False)
    soup2= BeautifulSoup(wcpage.text, 'html.parser')
    (soup2.prettify())
    print(soup2.find_all('body'))
    for tr in soup2.find_all('body', class_="weather"):
Weather()
```

Comment: The last line in `Weather` is an unfinished for loop.

Comment: `for tr in soup2.find_all('body', class_="weather"):` is the start of a loop. So python is expecting the body of a loop, which should be indented. So its expecting an indent block.

Comment: You need to do **something** in that loop, but it definitely should **not** be calling that Weather function recursively

Comment: i guess  it should have a `print(tr)` after the for?

Comment: Thank you, I just started coding yesterday so I'm still making simple mistakes

Comment: No worries, @Cgreg, but please make sure you include what you expect your code to do in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments your last line in Weather() function is a for loop that is unfinished which isn't allowed in Python. If you wish to do nothing in this loop you should use the pass keyword like so:

```
for tr in soup2.find_all('body', class_="weather"):
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate the help. I already got banned for a week from asking questions because of this one.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop needs to do something. To do nothing, use the 'pass' keyword.

```
def Weather():
    zipcode = input('Please enter zipcode: ')
    wcpage = requests.get('https://weather.com/weather/today/l/' + zipcode,verify=False)
    soup2= BeautifulSoup(wcpage.text, 'html.parser')
    (soup2.prettify())
    print(soup2.find_all('body'))
    for tr in soup2.find_all('body', class_="weather"):
        """DO SOMETING HERE"""
Weather()
```